# Associate Apple ID with two different SIM cards (phone numbers)

Tags: apple-id, sim

I live in Canada but travel to the States and when I do I put in my American SIM card which of course has a different phone number. Sometimes when in the States I get locked out of my account and it sends a verification code to my Canadian number, but I don't really want to put the SIM card back in the phone just to get the code.  Is there any way I can have the verification code go to both numbers simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

If you have another phone, you can forward both phone calls and messages from one number to another. If you have another iPhone, you can forward messages for free - just go to Settings > Messages > Text Message Forwarding. This will make the message appear on both devices within a minute or so of each other. If you don't have an iPhone, I expect other phones would have an SMS forwarding capability, but there would be a per message cost.

I use this so I don't have to carry a work and personal phone, and it works well. The only complication you have is that it is in 2 different countries, so there will be roaming charges (I expect).